# Comment upvote arrows move after un-upvote in the mobile web

Tags: bug, comments, mobile-web, comment-voting

When I upvote a comment, it's marked. When I un-upvote it, the upvote sign doesn't go back, but moves left.

[image: vote moved to the left]

Comment: Still repro'd on Android 6.0.1, Chrome 47.0.2526.83